# Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header. in nodejs paypal sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to implement paypal subscription api in react-nodejs project.i refer https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/. after that i got id wit "P-*********".
What i have tried is:

1. in Ui Side(React) i created an event for requesting server side to create the billing plans.
2. in server side(nodejs) i do billingPlan create and update actions.

The code is:(nodejs)

```
export const paypalSubscribe = async (user, data) => {
  const customerId = user.customer,
{ invoice: invoiceId } = data;

try {
    const billingPlanAttributes = {
  description: "Create Plan for Regular",
  merchant_preferences: {
    auto_bill_amount: "yes",
    cancel_url: "http://www.cancel.com",
    initial_fail_amount_action: "continue",
    max_fail_attempts: "1",
    return_url: "http://www.success.com",
    setup_fee: {
      currency: "USD",
      value: "25"
    }
  },
  name: "Testing1-Regular1",
  payment_definitions: [
    {
      amount: {
        currency: "USD",
        value: order.price.recurringAmount
      },
      charge_models: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency: "USD",
            value: "10.60"
          },
          type: "SHIPPING"
        },
        {
          amount: {
            currency: "USD",
            value: "20"
          },
          type: "TAX"
        }
      ],
      cycles: "0",
      frequency: "MONTH",
      frequency_interval: order.billingCycle,
      name: "Regular 1",
      type: "REGULAR"
    }
  ],
  type: "INFINITE"
};

const createdBillingPlan = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttributes, function (
    error,
    billingPlan
  ) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(billingPlan);
    }
  });
});

console.log("data123....", createdBillingPlan);

// update
var billing_plan_update_attributes = [
  {
    op: "replace",
    path: "/",
    value: {
      state: "ACTIVE"
    }
  }
];

console.log(
  "billing_plan_update_attributes",
  billing_plan_update_attributes
);

const updateBillingPlan = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Paypal.billingPlan.update(
    createdBillingPlan.id,
    billing_plan_update_attributes,
    function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    }
  );
});

const getBillingPlan = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Paypal.billingPlan.get(createdBillingPlan.id, function (
    error,
    updatedBillingPlan
  ) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("errr", error.response);
      reject(error);
    } else {
      console.log("updatedBillingPlan", JSON.stringify(updatedBillingPlan));
      resolve(updatedBillingPlan);
      updatedBillingPlan.redire
    }
  });
});
console.log("getBillingPlan", getBillingPlan);
return { ok: true, data: getBillingPlan };
} catch (error) {
console.log("error", error);
}
};
```

And i got getBillingPlan is like this:

```
  { id: 'P-**************',
    state: 'ACTIVE',
    name: 'Testing1-Regular1',
    description: 'Create Plan for Regular',
    type: 'INFINITE',
    payment_definitions:
    [ { id: 'PD-0EF41434TA3045459BCMIRMA',
   name: 'Regular 1',
   type: 'REGULAR',
   frequency: 'Month',
   amount: [Object],
   cycles: '0',
   charge_models: [Array],
   frequency_interval: '1' } ],
    merchant_preferences:
   { setup_fee: { currency: 'USD', value: '25' },
 max_fail_attempts: '1',
 return_url: 'http://www.success.com',
 cancel_url: 'http://www.cancel.com',
 auto_bill_amount: 'YES',
 initial_fail_amount_action: 'CONTINUE' },
 create_time: '2020-07-01T04:18:01.008Z',
 update_time: '2020-07-01T04:18:02.031Z',
 links:
      [ { href:
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-***********',
   rel: 'self',
   method: 'GET' } ],
   httpStatusCode: 200 
   }
```

And when i trying to open the links in links array
ie,https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-***********' i got the error:

```
"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization 
header."
```

Where i went wrong? How can i resolve this and implement subscription of paypal in my Project.

**REST Api**

i changed my code to rest api calls finaly i got response like this:

```
{ status: 'APPROVAL_PENDING',
  id: 'I-1FU83BNMBCFS',
  create_time: '2020-07-06T09:47:02Z',
  links:
       [ { href:
    'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions? ba_token=BA-3D945638N1691194P',
   rel: 'approve',
   method: 'GET' },
 { href:
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I- 1FU83BNMBCFS',
   rel: 'edit',
   method: 'PATCH' },
 { href:
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-1FU83BNMBCFS',
   rel: 'self',
   method: 'GET' } ],
   responseCode: 201 }
```

and in my ui side i opened the approval link in new window after submitting it shows 404. Why?

code:

```
 window.open(URL, "_blank");
```

UPDATE:Subscription:

```
 const subscriptionString = {
    plan_id: result.id,
    start_time: "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    shipping_amount: {
      currency_code: "USD",
      value: "10.00"
    },
    subscriber: {
      name: {
        given_name: "John",
        surname: "Doe"
      },
      email_address: "customer@example.com",
      shipping_address: {
        name: {
          full_name: "John Doe"
        },
        address: {
          address_line_1: "2211 N First Street",
          address_line_2: "Building 17",
          admin_area_2: "San Jose",
          admin_area_1: "CA",
          postal_code: "95131",
          country_code: "US"
        }
      }
    },
    application_context: {
      brand_name: "walmart",
      locale: "en-US",
      shipping_preference: "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
      user_action: "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
      payment_method: {
        payer_selected: "PAYPAL",
        payee_preferred: "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"
      },
      return_url: "https://example.com/returnUrl",
      cancel_url: "https://example.com/cancelUrl"
    }
  },
  options = {
    url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(subscriptionString)
  },
  activateResult = await payment.callPayaplApi(options);


  return {
      ok: true,
      data: activateResult
  };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK for a Subscriptions API integration, you need to implement direct REST API calls.

The PayPal-Node-SDK never supported the Subscriptions API, only the previous billing APIs which are not compatible. Also, the PayPal-Node-SDK is no longer maintained.

You particular authentication error is due to something else, but due to the above issues it is not worth troubleshooting.

Start over and integrate correctly with direct REST API calls.

Comment: can you please give any samples?

Comment: There are curl samples at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/ , so basically do those same types of HTTPS calls in node.js

Comment: As you mentioned like i made REST API calls. but i got "404" after submit

Comment: Make sure you use the right HTTP method (GET/POST) and URL.  You'll have to provide full details otherwise.

Comment: Where is your approval button? Follow the guide at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#subscriptions-with-smart-payment-buttons

Comment: am not using Smart Payment Buttons in the JavaScript SDK am using Subscriptions REST API then why should i render the button? i simply place a button in ui side and make a call to server side for subscription and i got the response in ui side and i tried to render the url in ui side (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions? ba_token=BA-3D945638N1691194P') then it  render the paypal site  and after agree and subscribe i git this "404".

Comment: That's not a valid URL, it's not the string the PayPal API returned. In any case there is absolutely no reason you should be redirecting when you can keep your site loaded with no redirect and provide an in-context experience. Use the button in the Subscriptions guide.